# Reading excel cells containing alphanumeric data in Java

Tags: java, excel, iterator, apache-poi

I am trying to get the values from cells in an excel spreadsheet that contain both letters and numbers. 
Below is a sample of my code:

```
 String excelFilePath = "FILEPATH";
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
 Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
 Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

 iterator.next();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();

                int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();

                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    String name = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Date enrollDate = nextCell.getDateCellValue();  
                case 2:
                    String userid = nextCell.getStringCellValue();                   
                }

            }
```

My question is in relation to case 2.User IDs can either be letters, numbers or a mix of both for example: (**AX77552, 112321, ASWTT**)
If I say getStringCellValue() I get an error and I also get an error if I say getNumericCellValue(). 
 Is there any way that I can make it so that you can get numeric and string values for the cells in this row of data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884318/how-to-read-alphanumeric-values-from-excel-cells-in-java

Comment: Check the cell type...

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC etc. were all removed in apache poi 4.0.0

Comment: @deHaar its a mix of numeric and text throughout, it is not one consistent type.

Comment: Can you show us the error message you get when you invoke `getStringCellValue()`?

Comment: @nb96 it took about 1 min to find out that `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` got replaced with enum `CellType.NUMERIC`, just use `cell.getCellType()` and that enum.

Comment: @Amongalen Thanks for the help!